# How to define an array of action spaces?

Tags: python, machine-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to create a crypto trading bot that can trade multiple crypto coins simulatenously. So for example if I have `n=4` coins (e.g. : 0-BTC, 1-ETH, 2-DOT, 3-SOL), then an example of action space would be something like:

```
action_spaces: [ 1000, 0.0, -3000, 2300]
```

Where:

- `BUY if action > 0`
- `HOLD if action == 0`
- `Sell if action < 0`

So, in the given example the actions would be:

- Index 0: Buy btc worth 1000 USDT
- Index 1: Hold eth
- Index 2: Sell DOT worth 3000 USDT
- Index 3: Buy SOL worth of 2300 USDT

So for an `n = x` with crypto list: `[crypto0, crypto1, crypto2, ..., cryptoX]` how can I define an action space that has the form: `action_space = [action0, action1, action2, ..., actionX]`

Comment: Why don't use a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest go with `dictionaries.` suppose you are having crypto list: `[crypto0, crypto1, crypto2, ..., cryptoX]` and action space `[action0, action1, action2, ..., actionX].`

```
crypto_list = ['crypto0', 'crypto1', 'crypto2', 'cryptoX']
action_space = ['action0', 'action1', 'action2', 'actionX']

cryto_action_map = dict(zip(crypto_list, action_space))

print(cryto_action_map)
```

which will give output like

```
{'crypto0': 'action0', 'crypto1': 'action1', 'crypto2': 'action2', 'cryptoX': 'actionX'}
```

from here you can iterate on each coin and action using `items` method.

```
for coin, action in cryto_action_map.items():
    if action > 0:
        # BUY logic
        
    elif action == 0:
        # HOLD logic
        
    elif action < 0:
        # SELL logic
```

REMEMBER **crypto_list** and **action_space** are 2 separate lists and `both should have same length.`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  In this case, can each action be of different length? For example: I hold 1 ETH (price 3800) and 2 DOT (price 25 each) and 2000 USDT. In the buy case, both eth and dot would have the buy action in range (0, 2000), but eth would have as sell action range [-3800,0) and DOT would have sell action range [-50, 0). Would that make a problem for the algorithm to figure it out? I'm using DDPG algorithm

Comment: for better understanding i need to see code.

Comment: The code you provided in the previous answer could serve as a good example (I do not have a personal implementation). So the trader would use the USDT reserve of an account, let's say that the trader can use up to 1000 USDT.  In that case, each element of `action_space` can range between [0, 1000].
Suppose that I own one crypto of each crypto from `crypto_list`. E.g. `crypto_list = ["eth", "dot", "sol"]`
At time `t0`, crypto0(eth) can be sold at `eth_price_t0`, crypto1(dot) can be sold at `dot_price_t0` and crypto2(sol) can be sold at `sol_price_t0`.

So at t0 the `action_space` would be:

Comment: `t0: action_space == [(etc_price_t0, 1000), (dot_price_t0, 1000), (sol_price_t0, 1000)]`
Since the prices are volatile, at time t1 there will be different selling prices, but the buying range would be the same(assuming that no USDT was used during t0 and t1):

`t1: action_space == [(etc_price_t1, 1000), (dot_price_t1, 1000), (sol_price_t1, 1000)]` where `etc_price_t0 != etc_price_t1 and dot_price_t0 != dot_price_t1 and sol_price_t0!=sol_price_t1`
So my question is whether the individual elements of the action space could be resized each iteration?